# Can you use IMemoryCache in a maui application - Getting null

Tags: xamarin.forms, maui

Not sure what I am doing wrong but I would like to use caching in a Maui application but  the values do not seem to be retained.

**In the maui Program I have**

```
 builder.Services.AddSingleton<IMemoryCache, MemoryCache>()
 using ServiceProvider? serviceProvider = builder.Services.BuildServiceProvider();
 var cache= serviceProvider.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
 cache?.Set("key", "someValue");
```

**android mainActivity**

```
var cache= MauiApplication.Current.Services.GetService(typeof(IMemoryCache)) as IMemoryCache;
var someValue=memoryCache.Get("key");
```

the cache object is there but there are no items in the cache ...someValue is null ?

what am I missing ? Why are the values not in the cache????

**Update when I read the cache value that was set earlier on its null but things start working once in the viewmodel**

```
private readonly IMemoryCache? cache;
public class MainActivity : MauiAppCompatActivity
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache? cache;

    public MainActivity()
    { 
        var serviceProvider = MauiApplication.Current.Services;
        cache = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMemoryCache))as IMemoryCache ;
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle? savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        var someValue = cache.Get("key");
    }
}
```

Comment: where/when are you calling it in `MainActivity`?

Comment: It’s called automatically by the Maui app lifecycle

Comment: that doesn't tell me anything.  What method is it called in?

Comment: **1)** Your MainActivity code snippet has a typo? `var cache =`, but then `... = memoryCache`? **2)** If you set breakpoints on the `Set` and `Get` lines, the `Set` is called first? **3)** If you do `Get` in cross-platform code (e.g. in MainPage), does it find the value?

Comment: @Jason apologises if not clear I am editing the question

Comment: `OnCreate` runs **first** - you are trying to read the cache before you have written to it

Comment: @Jason I thought that too - but when I run in debug - the order I see and I now I have doubts is 1)MauiProgram - 2)AddServices (part of MauiProgram) 3)MainActivity constructor 4)OnCreate

Answer (score 1):

You could access and set the cache in App.xaml, like the following

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new AppShell();
        var cache = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IMemoryCache)) as IMemoryCache;
    cache?.Set("key2", "someValue2");
    }
}
```

Hope it works for you.